# What is the missing number?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

What is the missing number?

9560,24208,25512,13560,279644,232928,101448,?

> HINT: Some debate there should be one more number after the missing number

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These are

> twice the diameter of the planets in our system.

The next number is

> 98496, twice the diameter of Neptune

one more number could be

> 4800, twice the diameter of Pluto.
>  There is a [debate](http://space.about.com/od/pluto/a/Should-Pluto-Be-A-Planet.htm) about pluto being a planet or not.

Comment: Correct! The unit is Km

Comment: @Maxim ahah touché. I only doubled them so people couldn't google the numbers

Comment: @JacobGoulden Sorry I deleted my comment because I had not seen this answer changed to "twice the diameter", for which the unit is really Km, instead of "diameter" ;)